# "Functions are not valid as a React child." error

Tags: javascript, reactjs, web-frontend

I'm a begginer on react and js. I'm trying to create a todo list and i get the "Functions are not valid as a React child." error. I tried a couple of solutions but they didn't do anything. Here is my code:

```
    const default_tasks = [
        {
            id: 1,
            name: 'Learn JavaScript',
            status: false
        },
        {
            id: 2,
            name: 'Learn React',
            status: false
        },
        {
            id: 3,
            name: 'Get a life',
            status: false
        }
      ];
      
      const [liste, setListe] = useState(default_tasks);


const addLiElement = () => {
        setListe(liste.map((item) => 
            <li className={item.status === true ? 'completed' : 'active'}
                key={item.id}
                >
                <div className='view'>
                    <input className='toggle'
                            type='checkbox'
                            onClick={() => markAsCompleted(item.id)}
                    />
                    <label>{item.name}</label>
                    <button className='destroy'></button>
                </div>
            </li>
        ))
      }
```

The place i'm trying to call the function:

```
<ul className="todo-list" id='main-ul'>{() => addLiElement()}</ul>
```

Lastly i know i can call the map method inside the  tag but i want to call it outside if it's possible.

Comment: You should remove your setListe call inside of addLiElement, it's probably a bad idea. Then you're adding an extra arrow function, if you remove it it should work better: `<ul className="todo-list" id='main-ul'>{addLiElement()}</ul>`

Comment: Thanks for the reply. When i did the things yo said i didn't get any error but i also couldn's see the list items on the page. That's why i used setListe and when i remove setListe it forces me to use an arrow function.

Comment: Can you add what is your code before you did that, there's probably another mistake.

Comment: I couldn't post the whole code here but here's the github link you can check it there: https://github.com/falconeer01/react-todo-list-def.git

Comment: You can edit your post to add the previous code. Also your github link is private so I'm getting a not found page

Comment: Sorry, I changed it to public now.

Comment: There's no return in your addLiItem method, so the function does not produce anything. Add a return and it will work ( in the previous functions you did not have brackets so it did not need a return)

Comment: Thank you so much for your help! Now I was able to run it with return.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to create a functional component, you need to return a JSX or HTML statement end of function. For this issue, you can do it like that at least that I understand:

```js
const addLiElement = () => {
        setListe([...liste, {id: liste.length + 1,
            name: 'Default name',
            status: false
         }])
}
```

and after that, you can map the array in the JSX, not unknown return typed method.

```
<ul className="todo-list" id='main-ul'>{liste.map((item) => 
            <li className={item.status === true ? 'completed' : 'active'}
                key={item.id}
                >
                <div className='view'>
                    <input className='toggle'
                            type='checkbox'
                            onClick={() => markAsCompleted(item.id)}
                    />
                    <label>{item.name}</label>
                    <button className='destroy'></button>
                </div>
            </li>
        )}</ul>
```